# How to display C# winforms chart x axis labels in descending order

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart which is populated with `DateTime` values in descending order, but the x axis labels are in ascending order. How do I get the labels to match the data?

```
foreach (var eventData in eventResultsFinal) 
{
    sensorTimeStamp = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(secondsSinceEpoch + 
                      Convert.ToInt32(eventData.t1)); 
    if (eventData.v1.Equals("active")) 
        chart1.Series[chartSeriesCounter].Points
              .AddXY(sensorTimeStamp.ToOADate(), 1 + yOffset); 
    else if (eventData.v1.Equals("inactive")) 
        chart1.Series[chartSeriesCounter].Points
              .AddXY(sensorTimeStamp.ToOADate(), 0 + yOffset); 
    }
}
```

[image]

See the image above - the timestamps are increasing, I would like them decreasing.

Comment: Please post a code that reproduce the problem and show how you add data to chart. Also posting an image describing the problem and requirement on image will be useful. Then probably you would receive more effective helps.

Comment: I use the following to add the data points

Comment: chart1.Series[chartSeriesCounter].Points.AddXY(sensorTimeStamp.ToOADate(), 1 + yOffset);

Comment: See the image above - the timestamps are increasing, I would like them decreasing.

Comment: There is a for loop or such code in your loop. Post it. Also take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `foreach (var eventData in eventResultsFinal)
{
 sensorTimeStamp = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(secondsSinceEpoch + Convert.ToInt32(eventData.t1));

 if (eventData.v1.Equals("active"))
  chart1.Series[chartSeriesCounter].Points.AddXY(sensorTimeStamp.ToOADate(), 1 + yOffset);
 else if (eventData.v1.Equals("inactive"))
  chart1.Series[chartSeriesCounter].Points.AddXY(sensorTimeStamp.ToOADate(), 0 + yOffset);
}`

Comment: @Studley you can post additional code or other information using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38439700/edit) button below your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show the data in a reversed order you can tell the X-axis to do so by setting its `IsReversed` property:

```
  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsReversed;
```

An alternative, but **not** recommended way would be to add the X-Values as `strings` instead of `DateTimes`. Then the `DataPoints` would be ordered in the same way you add them, but you could not really work with the X-values anymore..

**Update**: Since Reversing the X-Axis also reverses the order of the Y-Axis placement you may want to set the Y-Axes like this:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

**Note**: All styling of the **primary Y-Axis** should now go to the **secondary** one (`AxisY2`), including any `CustomLabels`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that method, but it places the y axis labels to right of the chart.

Comment: Thanks - The time is now descending, but that stops my custom labels from being shown.  I dont understand why disabling Y and enabing Y2 makes the time line appear as I want.

Comment: Well you just have to add those CustomLabels to the other Y-Axis: AxisY2.CustomLabels.Add(..). You may want to read up on the [secondary axes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489216%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)